# Current Ip redirecting to another IP?

Tags: magento2

Hi i have installed magento2.0 in my PC and i moved total bakeup including database to another PC

When i run the file using ip in that configured system its redirecting to my IP

Please tell me the solution?

I have moved all the files and i have imported DB and then changed path in coreconfig file also still its redirecting to my IP.

Answer (score 1):

When you access a Magento website, it checks the URL you used with the one stored in the database as `base url`. In case it's not the same URL, it redirects you to the one from the database.

To change the base url you need to access the database, table `core_config_data` and look for entries with path `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` which you need to update with the new url

Comment: @user5506072 any luck? would be great if we could close this question

Answer (score 0):

i was getting this issue recently.
did you try deleting var/cache and var/generation folder?
if all the config steps are ok, maybe that is the problem.
cheers!